# Metabox collapsed by default

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, metabox, dashboard

I need to make a metabox of a WordPress Plugin called "post expirator" collapsed by default.

Right now it is open.

actually when i open a  page  :

[image]

My need :
[image]

That is the part of the code adding metaboxe :

```
 * Adds hooks to get the meta box added to pages and custom post types
 */
function expirationdate_meta_custom() {
    $custom_post_types = get_post_types();
    array_push($custom_post_types,'page');
    foreach ($custom_post_types as $t) {
        $defaults = get_option('expirationdateDefaults'.ucfirst($t));
        if (!isset($defaults['activeMetaBox']) || $defaults['activeMetaBox'] == 'active') {
            add_meta_box('expirationdatediv', __('Post Expirator','post-expirator'), 'expirationdate_meta_box', $t, 'side', 'core');
        }
    }
}
add_action ('add_meta_boxes','expirationdate_meta_custom');
```

Thanks in advance for the reply.

Comment: [Questions about third-party plugins are off-topic here.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) You'll have to ask in the plugin's official support streams.

Comment: I have not an answer from the support. that why i'm here. I think a need to add some code line on the code i post so i'm looking for a help